# How to get rid of the older versions of custom diagnostic data adapter appearing in the MTM

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am using MTM 2010 for runing automated tests and implemented a custom diagnostic data adapter (DDA) collecting log files which are created when tests are running.

When I perform some changes on the DDA implementation and increment its assembly version and deploy the new version to the machine MTM is running on this DDA appears over again in the list of DDAs in MTM (meanwhile I have three of them in the list)

**How can I get rid of the older versions of my DDA appearing in the MTM?**

It seems like there are some "artifacts" stored on TFS for each assembly version (GUID).

If I try to set up an older version of DDA hitting one in MTM I get a warning that the editor can not be startet so I only can edit the XML representation of the DDA settings.

That is a kind of "verification" the older version is really not installed anymore.
It really looks like if DDA of a particular version will be recognized by MTM for the first time the information about it will be stored somewhere on TFS...

***Additional information:***

If I deploy a new version of DDA the files belonging to the old version will be overridden.
I deploy new version to:

- a machine MTM is running on (in order to be able to set up this DDA)
- a VM where my tests are running on (where a Test Agent is installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution, see following blog:
[Unregister a Data Collector from TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shivash/archive/2012/01/20/unregister-a-data-collector-from-tfs.aspx)